# interface issue

Tags: c#, interface

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [IF structure issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040476/if-structure-issue)
>   [Logic problem while setting conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026530/logic-problem-while-setting-conditions)

I have the following code:

```
foreach (DataModelObject dmo in allObjects)
{
    if (string.Compare(dmo.Name, hostName, true) == 0)
    {
        if (dmo is IResourcePolicy)
        {
            IResourcePolicy irp = (IResourcePolicy)dmo;
            irp.ResourcePolicy = rp;
            irp.AgentPolicyVersion.Version = Convert.ToInt64(policyVersion);
            irp.ResourcePolicyEnabled = Convert.ToBoolean(enabled);
            irp.AgentVersion = agentVersion;

            // Distribute the object without saving it.
            SpoServer.Spurt.ServerSendObject(dmo, true, 0);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

here i want to assign "irp.AgentVersion = agentVersion;" outside of the main loop and more over neglecting the loop if (dmo is IResourcePolicy)
like this way
if i am doing this way

```
foreach (DataModelObject dmo in allObjects)
{
    IResourcePolicy irpa ;
    irpa.AgentVersion = agentVersion;
}
```

i am getting error Error Use of unassigned local variable 'irpa'

what shall i do here?

Comment: do we need to use property concept here

Comment: peter, you're asking the same question again and again. Rephrasing it every time a little bit doesn't help. We still don't know what you're trying to achieve. We don't know your data model. Please tell us **exactly** what you're trying to do, or stop asking the same question again and again.

Comment: Where exactly do you want to run that code? The issue you're running into is that "irpa" has no value: it is null. Because you don't have an actual IResourcePolicy object you can't assign values to its properties because you don't actually have an object yet!

Comment: Duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026530 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040476 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043374

Comment: Ehm...does this guy want to spam Stackoverflow always placing the same question??? Come on..

Comment: What does `irpa` represent? What do you want to assign actually?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve, but here are some options:

If `DataModelObject` class contains the `AgentVersion` property, you can simply do it like this (although this is most likely not the case):

```
foreach (DataModelObject dmo in allObjects)
{
    dmo.AgentVersion = agentVersion;
}
```

If `AgentVersion` is implemented only in **some** derived classes (not all), then you need to check explicitly it the derived class implements that interface, like you are doing right now:

```
foreach (DataModelObject dmo in allObjects)
{
    if (dmo is IResourcePolicy)
    {
         IResourcePolicy policy = (IResourcePolicy)dmo;
         policy.AgentVersion = agentVersion;
    }
}
```

Third case would be that you have several derived classes which don't implement the same interface, but still have the `AgentVersion` property. The cleanest way to fix that (if you can change the source code) would be to have all these objects implement the same interface, containing properties which are common to them all:

```
interface IAgentVersion
{
     string AgentVersion { get; }
     // omit other properties which are not common to all objects
}

interface IResourcePolicy : IAgentVersion
{
     string ResourcePolicy { get; }
     // ...
     // add all policy-specific properties
}
```

Now you are sure that all `IAgentVersion` and `IResourcePolicy` objects implement that common property (`AgentVersion`), and you only need to check for the base interface:

```
foreach (DataModelObject dmo in allObjects)
{
    if (dmo is IAgentVersion)
    {
         IAgentVersion = (IAgentVersion)dmo;
         policy.AgentVersion = agentVersion;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not know exactly what you want to achieve. I can only highlight your errors:

```
foreach (DataModelObject dmo in allObjects)
{
    IResourcePolicy irpa ; // <-- declaring but not instantiated or assigned
    irpa.AgentVersion = agentVersion; // <-- hence this error...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

irpa is an instance of a class, meaning it's a reference type. A reference type variable needs to be initialized with the new() operator or it needs to point to an existing variable of the same type using the '=' operator.

```
IResourcePolicy irpa = new IResourcePolicy() ;
irpa.AgentVersion = agentVersion;
```

However, the syntax indicates that irpa might be an Interface - which is abstract and thus unusable in this way